# A website offering (R)DBMS as service?

Tags: web-services, rdbms

Couple of days ago I came across a website that offered (R)DBMS as a service. I did not find it useful at that moment. Now I might have changed my mind and I just can't find that website anywhere in the browser history.

I recall that it only required an email address to send you the db/account info to. And there was the line "yes, that's it/all" or something like that.

Anyone knows that website?

P.S.: I'm sorry, I know this is not what people typically ask at SO, but I think other developers might know more likely than anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of [Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/)?

Comment: nope, this one was something very young, i mean a new project

Answer (score 1):

Could it be [CloudBoost.io](https://www.cloudboost.io)? You can even check [this directory](http://dbaas.wordpress.com/database-as-a-service-dbaas-product-directory/) out, as ErikE suggested.  :

Answer (score 0):

Was it [FathomDB](http://fathomdb.com/about/home), perhaps?

Perhaps the [Database as a Service Product Directory](http://dbaas.wordpress.com/database-as-a-service-dbaas-product-directory/) could be helpful to you.

Comment: unfortunately no, the one i'm searching for had very minimalistic welcome-page